# calling main timeline from within a movieclip with javaScript (Animate CC)

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate, adobe, timeline

My problem is that using Animate CC, I want to target the main timeline from within a movie clip and I do not know the syntax to refer to it.  In AS3, the main timeline could be referred to as "_root".

What I am trying to do seems so simple, yet I'm stumped even after searching the interwebs.  I would like to have a movie clip sit on frame one of the main timeline with a stop action on that frame.  When the movieclip's timeline runs its course, i would it to stop and to tell the main timeline to move forward to frame two.

How do I refer to the main timeline using javaScript?  Is there an equivalent to root?

Answer (score 0):

To access your timeline from a child use `MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(2);`

Using JavaScript you can't directly access flash displayObjects, but you can implement some externally visible interfaces to control your flash code

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
ExternalInterface.addCallback("functionNameVisibleInJS", apropriateFunctionInFlash);

function apropriateFunctionInFlash(parameter1:String = ""):void
{
    //Some code, for example:
    gotoAndStop(int(parameter1));
}
```

To use it from JS just call

```
flashContainer.functionNameVisibleInJS(2);
```

Don't forget to setup appropriate privileges for your flash object in Embed tag:

```
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
```

More info: http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#addCallback()